# Python Flask - Increment request.path

Tags: python-3.x, flask

```
<a href="{{ request.path }}"></a>
```

Iam essentially looking to do the following:

```
<a href="{{ request.path = request.path +1 }}"></a>
```

request.path is returning "/image/". I need to increment the . So I need to increment .

This is the route:

```
@app.route('/image', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/image/<int:image_id>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def image(image_id):
    image = Images.query.filter_by(id=image_id).first_or_404()
    return render_template('image.html', image=image)
```

Should I be looking into splitting the path?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

On the route pass image_id into the template:

```
m=image_id
```

In the template:

```
<a href="{{ m+1 }}"> xx </a></li>
```